# Jquery set quotes in quote

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such code:

```
$("input[id="+id.slice(0,-1)+"-br-"+brand+"].qnt_to_cart").show();
```

which generate me:

```
input[id=02620-br-FEBI BILSTEIN].qnt_to_cart
```

But i need to see something like:

```
input[id="02620-br-FEBI BILSTEIN"].qnt_to_cart
```

So what i need to write? How to set quote in quote?

**upd**

why i still see:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[id=02620-br-FEBI BILSTEIN].to-cart
```

Answer (score 6):

use `\"` to escape quotes:

```
$("input[id=\""+id.slice(0,-1)+"-br-"+brand+"\"].qnt_to_cart").show();
```

Comment: i see in error Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[id=02620-br-FEBI BILSTEIN].to-cart     ....

Answer (score 2):

`$('input[id="'+id.slice(0,-1)+'-br-'+brand+'"].qnt_to_cart').show();`

Comment: why i still see:
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[id=02620-br-FEBI BILS.......

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris please show your code out. I think there may be same typo.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple options in JavaScript, you can contain them in `'` instead of `"`:

```
$('input[id="'+id.slice(0,-1)+'-br-'+brand+'"].qnt_to_cart').show();
```

or you can escape the quotes via `\"`:

```
$("input[id=\""+id.slice(0,-1)+"-br-"+brand+"\"].qnt_to_cart").show();
```

Comment: why i still see:
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[id=02620-br-FEBI BILS....

Comment: You have a space in `brand` (`"FEBI BILS"`) - I don't think querySelector supports an id with spaces in it