# cartItem.innerHTML =" this line shows Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript

```
const cartItem=document.createElement('div');
        cartItem.className="cart-item d-flex justify-content-between text-capitalize my-3";
        
        cartItem.innerHTML = "
        <img src="${item.img}" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" id="item-img" alt="" width="50" height="50">
        <div class="item-text">

          <p id="cart-item-title" class="font-weight-bold mb-0">${item.name}</p>
          <span>$</span>
          <span id="cart-item-price" class="cart-item-price" class="mb-0">${item.price}</span>
        </div>
        <a href="#" id='cart-item-remove' class="cart-item-remove">
          <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
        </a>";
```

Comment: You can not nest same quotes in JS. Also the [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as well as multiline strings are not working with double quotes.

Comment: See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610432/jquery-set-quotes-in-quote) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript).

Comment: Change to `cartItem.innerHTML = \`<img ...... <a>\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use template literals instead of quotes

```js
cartItem.innerHTML = `
        <img src="${item.img}" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" id="item-img" alt="" width="50" height="50">
        <div class="item-text">

          <p id="cart-item-title" class="font-weight-bold mb-0">${item.name}</p>
          <span>$</span>
          <span id="cart-item-price" class="cart-item-price" class="mb-0">${item.price}</span>
        </div>
        <a href="#" id='cart-item-remove' class="cart-item-remove">
          <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
        </a>`;
```

Comment: You have enough rep to post comments.

Comment: Thanx a lot .its working now